# Does the verb after 'set of' agree with 'set' or the plural noun that follows?

Tags: verb-agreement, relative-clauses, subjects

Does the verb after 'a set of + plural noun' agree with 'set' or 'noun'? For example:

> 'Law is a set of rules that govern/governs society.'

Comment: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=set+of+rules+that+govern%2Cset+of+rules+that+governs&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Answer (score 6):

In a **main clause** where "a set of rules" is the subject, the verb should be singular to agree with "set" (the head of the noun phrase):

> A set of rules governs society.

---

In your example, you build a **relative clause** that can refer to either "set or "rules". Hence, both are possible with a minute shift in meaning.

Singular, the verb agreeing with "set":

> ...a set of rules which governs socitey

means

> There is a set of rules, and **this set** governs society.

Plural, the verb agreeing with "rules":

> ...a set of rules which govern society

means

> There is a set of rules, and **these rules** govern society.

Answer (score -1):

It should be followed by *govern* because it doesn't follow *a set* but *rules*, which is plural.

Comment: I did not vote you down, but your example is not optimal. Try it with "The Indian Nation is a group of peoples who want(s) to gain a voice in the community"

Comment: @mplungjan Changed it to guys.

Comment: Ditto with mplungjan. *Group* can be treated as a plural and *there's* is simply a dummy marker. But in the OP's example, the initial *Law is* does not function like *There's* **and** *set* is generally treated as a single unit.

Comment: Andrew is correct. "The bloodhound gang, is a group of guys who want(s) to talk to you" - there is an expression in grammar I cannot remember where the s before the word in question begs plural